# Вывод записи с заданной по необходимую

Tags: java, android

Подключаю файл, допустим из 10 записей записанных в столбик как можно вывести записи с 4 по 7 допустим.
Вот код где я подключаю

```
 public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stm3);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
            if (count>21) {
                arr.add(line);
            }
            count++;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывести куда именно?
Вообще, если у Вас есть список строк, который Вы хотите, например, вывести в лог, то по нему можно пройтись обычным `for`.

```
// Четвёртая запись будет иметь индекс 3
for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++) {
    Log.d("AnyTag", listOfStrings.get(i));
}
```

Или Вы можете объединить элементы списка одной строкой для отображения в `TextView`:

```
// Седьмая запись будет иметь индекс 6
// первый параметр -- это символ, который будет вставлен между объединяемыми строками
String oneBigString = TextUtils.join("\n", listOfStrings.subList(3, 6));
yourTextView.setText(oneBigString);
```

**UPD**: Для отображения в `ListView` необходимо использовать адаптер. Вообще, это обширная тема, лучше почитать в документации или поискать туториалы (например, [этот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/arrayadapter.php)), но наиболее простой вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
    context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfString.subList(3, 6)));
```

Первый параметр -- это контекст, обычно активити, которая содержит `ListView`.
Второй -- это некий лэйаут, в данном примере используется готовый из SDK, который содержит просто один `TextView`. 
Третий -- список элементов для отображения.

Comment: вывожу в листвию

Comment: ну я уже разобрался пасибо